# How to determine AMD OpenCl CPU Device and GPU Devices are running parallel?

Tags: opencl

I have four jobs (grouped in two tasks) need to be executed on AMD OpenCl device and GPU Device parallely. As per my knowledge, calling NDRangeKernel for AMD OpenCl CPU Device, is returning promptly (non blocking) if NULL event is passed.

**TASK1**
Hence, firstly i am calling NDRangeKernel for AMD OpenCl CPU Device with NDRangeKernel for job1, after which host will have the control promptly.

```
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue_amd, icm_kernel_amd, 1, NULL, &glob, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

**TASK2**
Then host can call NDRangeKernel for GPU Device using gpu kernel 1 for job2 and then for gpu kernel 2 for job3 and then gpu kernel 3 for job4 which will call them serially.

```
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue_gpu, icm_kernel_gpu[0], 1, NULL, &glob, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue_gpu, icm_kernel_gpu[1], 1, NULL, &glob, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue_gpu, icm_kernel_gpu[2], 1, NULL, &glob, &local, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

They are not returning promptly to host.

And then reading buffer for GPU and then for CPU.

```
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue_gpu, Buffer_gpu, CL_TRUE, 0, count * sizeof(double), arr_gpu, 0, NULL, NULL);
ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue_amd, Buffer_amd, CL_TRUE, 0, count * sizeof(double), arr_cpu, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

My question is, is both the tasks are running parallely? Is there any profiler/logic to detect such behaviour? Any commments/logics/pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know they are not returning promptly? The call will take sometime to complete the queueing process, but that does not mean it is a blocking call. You should check the events of the calls to see their status after your calls.  BTW: Kernels never run in parallel in a device, only the WIs inside the kernel call run in parallel.

Comment: yes @DarkZeros kernels never run in parallel. But is that applied to different devices? In my case, devices are different. And i am expecting the same for GPU Device, but i am just suggesting for AMD OpenCL Device separate with 1 kernel and GPU device separate with 3 kernels running serially? hence my query is, is both devices are executing parallel?

Comment: You are using the same Queue `command_queue_gpu` for all the GPU cases, so there, it doesn't matter if you launch 1, 3 or 1k kernels, they are going to be serial. As for the CPU and GPU devices, yes, they do run in parallel (check it by looking at the event data).

Comment: That answer my question. Please post it in answer column, so that i can mark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me write a proper answer:

The parallel execution of the kernels depends on the device/queue model used.
In the general "spec" point of view:

- **A queue** runs the jobs in order (no overlap or parallel execution possible). Unless the queue has the property "out-of-order-exec", in which case parallel execution and disordered execution is possible, and everything will be controlled based on events.

But from the HW point of view: (nVIDIA, AMD, etc)

- **A device** can only run one kernel at a time. Therefore, if a queue can only act to a device, a queue can't process kernels in parallel.

---

**In a multi-device setting**, this constrain is relaxed, and the kernels can run in parallel in different devices. But in order to be able to run fully parallel there are some rules to meet:

- The chain for each device should be completely separate. Kernel, Queue, memory, etc (context can be the same).
- If the memory has to be shared, it is recommended to have a proper fine control of it. Kernels writing to the same memory can lead to blocking of one of them.
- In case that a kernel uses as input the output of another kernel, the execution will not be parallel.

---

In order to measure if "in fact" parallel execution is working I recommend to use **events**.

You can do it the hard way (manually) or you can use CodeXL, nSight or Intel SDK. They will collect this metrics for you by hooking the OpenCL calls, and give you the insight you need (in a very convenient format with figures and statistics).

Comment: Thanks DarkZeros. Helped a lot.

Comment: Device can optionally run multiple kernels at a time.

Comment: Can you detail how can it be done? As far as I know the HW does not allow that to happen.

Comment: Latest generations of AMD & Nvidia cards supports concurrent kernel execution (Nvidia supports up to 16 parallel kernels). CPU devices support it for a long time (e. g. through fission).

Answer (score 1):

Though, comment about Command Queue was made, there is something to add.

You can use AMD CodeXL tool to collect application timeline & see if tasks are done in parallel. Or another very simple solution - look at CPU load level in your OS Task Manager and simultaneously do the same for GPU in Catalyst Center. If load levels are increasing at the same time - tasks are done in parallel.